# How to tell AppCenter to use specific .env file React Native

Tags: react-native, continuous-integration, visual-studio-app-center, continuous-delivery

I'm wondering how can I set up the MS AppCenter to use the specific .env file, let' say the **.env.staging** for example:

[image]

and the CI/CD of the AppCenter will do the build for me with that .env file

Answer (score 1):

If you have separate branches for `staging`, `release` etc. this can be made to work.

For each of the branches have a common environment variable to identify the specific release. Ex: `TARGET = staging`
(Or you can even use Appcente's pre-defined variable `APPCENTER_BRANCH` to grab the branch name. Depends on the strategy you follow.)

Next create a either a `appcenter-pre-build.sh` or `appcenter-post-build.sh` and update it as follows. This will create a copy of your `TARGET` env file as `.env`

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# Appcenter pre-build hook to setup amplify.
set -e
IFS='|'

echo "Making a copy of .env file"
cp .env.${TARGET} .env
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. Where can I set the TARGET = staging? P.S. Yes, I have test branch for staging and main for release, how can I tell that release is for main branch and staging for test branch? Thank you very much in advance! Will let you know if it works and accept your solution

Comment: In build configuration hover over to environment section. https://imgur.com/a/04BeUPs

Refer [Appcenter documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/build/custom/variables/) for more information

Comment: You need to manually set the environment variable in each of the build configurations for those 3 branches.
However IMO its not a good idea to keep the environment variables with secrets within the repository.